# Background mode with NSTimers and server calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, background-process

I'm working on an sdk that uses NSTimer to make a server call when it expires at x mins and the server call resets the timer back to x mins after doing some work. The problem I'm having is that my timer stops running when my app is in the background and resumes immediately when my app is back in the foreground. How do I get this to work?

```
//initialize self.myTimer somewhere in my code
//called once somewhere in my code-->[self resetTimer:self.myTimer expiry:30];

- (void)resetTimer:(NSTimer *)timer expiry:(float)seconds {
[timer invalidate];
NSTimer *newTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:seconds
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(updateTimer:)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:newTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

self.myTimer = newTimer;

}

- (void) updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {

    [timer invalidate];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("update", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self serverCall];
    });
}

-(void)serverCall{
//make server call and do some work
[self resetTimer:self.myTimer expiry:30];


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The timer won't continue to fire when the app is in the background.  If you're willing to let the OS set the pace of the server calls, you can accomplish this by consulting the section "Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically" in this [background execution doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

The gist is to set your app's `UIBackgroundModes` key == fetch in info.plist.

When iOS decides to grant your app some cycles, you can run a *short* task in:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler {
    [self serverCall];  // BUT! read on
}
```

But you'll need to refactor your `serverCall` to tell the caller when its done.  Otherwise, you won't know when to invoke the `completionHandler:`.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler {
    [self newServerCallWithCompletion:^(BOOL gotNewData) {
        UIBackgroundFetchResult result = (gotNewData)? UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData : UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData;
        completionHandler(result);
    }];
}
```

See the docs for more options on [UIBackgroundFetchResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBackgroundFetchResult).

With this, iOS will set the pace of requests, so you won't be able to make them *more often* than when you're app is given the chance.  By persisting the time of the last request, you can make requests *less often*.  Just check if the interval since the last request is `<=` to some desired max frequency.  If it is, just call the completionHandler right away with "no data".

Comment: The performFetchWithCompletionHandler method seems to be only available in the app delegate. I'm currently working on a static library that has no appdelegate. I could add that to my test app that uses my static library, but that defeats the purpose of having a static library. I still want to use my timers when I'm in the foreground to perform server calls and switch to another method that allows me to perform server calls when my app is in the background. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, the timer approach is fine in the foreground.  But the only way to perform processing in the background is via hooks in the app delegate.  To do this in a library, you'll have to give your library's customer installation instructions to configure the info.plist and to add a call to your library in the app delegate.  (you'd want the customer of the library to be aware of and approve background processing anyway).

Comment: What happens if I have different server calls that I want call at different times? Lets say I have timer A at 5 mins that calls Method A and Timer B at 10 mins that calls Method B. The timers work fine in the foreground, but how do I set up the equivalent in background fetch with performFetchWithCompletionHandler?

Comment: Outside of controlling pace, you can do whatever you want when invoked in the background. So to get differential actions when invoked, instead of letting the timer tell you, persist a little state saying what you did last time or what needs doing next time.  Just remember to run quick and call the completion handler.